# Woocommerce login form not working on a particular page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

The Woocommerce login form isn't working on only a single page.

Link: https://alexllc.org/labs/

To try logging in you need to hover over "Ahoy, Guest" and click "Log In." I can't give out login info for security, but if you just click the "Log In" button without filling anything out it will reload and if you open up the popup again you'll notice it doesn't give any error message. It gives error messages on every other page in this scenario. You can also login from every other page properly with correct login info. This is the ***only*** page giving issues.

I get this error when trying to log in:

```
POST https://alexllc.org/labs/?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments 403 (Forbidden) jquery.js:4
```

The same page works properly on the test environment. The live site has AIOWPS installed and if I disable all Firewall Rules it causes you to get a 404 page trying to log in from this page rather than just reloading it without logging you in.

This form is called using the [woocommerce_my_account] shortcode. The popup is included the same way everywhere, so I'm not sure what could be causing this page in particular to have the issue. Not sure what other code I should/can really share that would help.

I'm happy to give a login to individuals confidentially so they can test it with me if needed.

Comment: form is submitted via server side and the page is reloaded.check the validation before the form submit

Comment: I'm not worried about when the validation happens. The form isn't submitting at all on this page.